# Sending html content over server from android

Tags: android, api

I am trying to send html file content to request parameter.
The problem area is on the server side, getting some extra characters.

```
 <!Document....>  the other side ?<!Document...>
```

Why this "?" mark comes.
Can any one help me to figure out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I got solution of my problem

```
import java.io.*;
```

public class UTF8ToAnsiUtils {

```
// FEFF because this is the Unicode char represented by the UTF-8 byte order mark (EF BB BF).
public static final String UTF8_BOM = "\uFEFF";

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out
                    .println("Usage : java UTF8ToAnsiUtils utf8file ansifile");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        boolean firstLine = true;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis,
                "UTF8"));
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "Cp1252"));
        for (String s = ""; (s = r.readLine()) != null;) {
            if (firstLine) {
                s = UTF8ToAnsiUtils.removeUTF8BOM(s);
                firstLine = false;
            }
            w.write(s + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            w.flush();
        }

        w.close();
        r.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

private static String removeUTF8BOM(String s) {
    if (s.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
        s = s.substring(1);
    }
    return s;
}
```

}

You will find more detail in this link..
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html